# Passing the props from one component to another in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass json state from component api to component chart. When I am trying log console it shows the data but in the constructor it does not seems to have them if I try this.state.json instead of this.props.json in console. All I am trying it get the data from this.state.json from api component and pass them to chart component when I am setting json: this.props.json. But the this.state.json inside chart is empty.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Hlavnicards from './Hlavnicards';
import Datatable from './Datatable';
import Chart from './Chart';
import Countrypicker from './Countrypicker';

 class Api extends Component  {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countries: [],
      global: [],
      date: [],
      chartdata: [],
      json: []

    };
}

   
      componentDidMount() {

        axios.get(`https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily`)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({ json: data })
             
        })
        
        axios.get(`api/corona2`)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ countries: data.Countries })
          this.setState({ global: data.Global })
          this.setState({ date: data.Date })
          
         })

         
      }

      render() {
        return (
            <div>
          
          <div class= "p-col-12"><Hlavnicards currentDate = {this.state.date} summary = {this.state.global} /></div>
          <div class= "p-col-12"><Countrypicker /></div>
          <div class= "p-col-12"><Chart json = {this.state.json} /></div>
          <div class= "p-col-12"><Datatable summaryCountries = {this.state.countries} /></div>
          </div>
              
       
        );
      }
}

export default Api;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card } from 'primereact/card';
import C3Chart from 'react-c3js';
import 'c3/c3.css';
import axios from 'axios';
class Charts extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    
        this.state = {
            
            json: this.props.json,


            keys: {
                x: 'reportDate',

                value: ['totalConfirmed', 'deaths.total']
            },
            names: {
                totalConfirmed: 'Infected',
                'deaths.total': 'Deaths'

            },
            types: {
                totalConfirmed: 'area-spline',
                'deaths.total': 'area-spline'
                // 'line', 'spline', 'step', 'area', 'area-step' are also available to stack
            },
            colors: {
                totalConfirmed: 'red',
                'deaths.total': 'black',
                
            },
            zoom: {
                enabled: true
            }

        };

    };


    render() {
        console.log(this.props.json);
        return (
           

            <div class="p-grid">

                <div class="p-col-6" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>

                    <Card>

                        <C3Chart axis={{
                            x: {
                                type: 'timeseries',
                                label: {
                                    text: 'Date',
                                    position: 'outer-center'
                                }
                            },
                            y: {
                                label: {
                                    text: 'Number of people',
                                    position: 'outer-middle'
                                }
                            },

                        }} data={this.state} />

                    </Card>

                </div>

            </div>


        );
    }
}

export default Charts;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you notice your class name is Charts and you call it as Chart

Since you went straight, call the following way:

> this.props.json

No need to state or anything

Comment: var json needs to be specified for c3js charts that is why I am trying to parse the data from props.json to this.json in charts

Answer (score 0):

I think its better do this

```
    axios.get(`https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily`).then(response => {
      this.setState({ json: response.data });
    });
```

it works for me , for second API do this

Comment: I know and it works like this but I want to have all axios requests only inside api component